# Front-facing camera of camera2 is getting dark on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using [google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) of [camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) to record videos, the Back-facing camera is ok. The only change I make in code is

```
 String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];
```

to switch to Front-facing camera. The preview is okay, but when I start to record it's getting too dark and after stop recording the darkness is gone.

Currently I am having this issue on Pixel 2 with Android 8.1.0, but there are other users having the same issue on different devices with different API levels.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I didn't, I switched third party libraries.